# How to add usage info when downloading a Resource function persistently?

Tags: usage-messages, resourcefunction

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PersistResourceFunction/ allows one to use a resource function as though it was a native function. However, hovering over the function does not show the usage pattern or a short description.

This can be found by using `ResourceFunction["RainbowText", "Usage"]`, for example, however, how can one incorporate that persistently across sessions when hovering over the function?

Comment: `addUsage[name_String, usage_String] := ToExpression[name <> "::usage = \""<>usage <> "\";"];`

Comment: @Somos Hello, thank you I thought about adding a usage message but then I think it would not be persistent across sessions. That's why I talked about adding a usage string using a package at the end of the post, it was an attempt at having a usage message across sessions by loading a package each time

Comment: I could also edit the init.m but I was wondering if there was a more natural way with resource functions somehow.

Comment: edited for clarification and shortening.